# Counting date time stamp occurrences

Tags: mysql, sql, dbeaver

I need to count how many datetimes stamps occur within each hour.

Say I have this timestamp 2012-03-22 15:33:56.0 and 2012-03-30 08:22:45.0 in a column called date_time.

How do I put the hour (15 and 8) and count how many times those timestamps occurred (1 and 1) into separate columns!

Anything helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following DBFiddle, you can use the HOUR() function on the date time column and aggregate results : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2eKrampo67wNSnCajmwTok/0